# iOS Development: Is there a way to read .trace files from command prompt without using instruments

Tags: ios, testing, automation, instruments

I am trying to do some performance testing for my application and am looking to monitor its certain metrics, specifically cpu usage amongst others. I want to make the process completely automated. I am able to create the .trace file and am looking for a solution to get meaningful information from the trace file. I want to do this on non jail broken devices so using top too is not feasible

Thanks for any pointers for finding cpu usage on non jail broken devices in an automated fashion.

-Kshitiz

Comment: you can, but it's not easy: [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/2210287).

Answer (score 2):

You can run Instruments to import the trace file and export it as CSV for analysis by a script. It's not strictly 100% command-line, but if you automate the Instruments export it will be close.

Or, try DTrace, but I'm not sure if that supports iOS trace formats.

Comment: Do you know the AppleScript to export the CSV file? I couldn't figure it out.