# XCode Instruments export data in automated script

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to make a script that does automated testing of app and at the end it exports the result data automatically into text file or excel. Is there way to export the result data programmatically in the script so I don't have to manually export the result after the test is done?

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/2210287)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the test using the command line tools you can write a small script to parse the resulting plist file (xml).