# Collecting system data from iOS device during automated testing

Tags: ios, usage-statistics

We are trying to build a mobile automated testing lab that has 20 or 30 devices and want to capture the utilizations on each device during testing. I'm looking to start with iOS devices. The type of data in Xcode Debug Instruments would be ideal. However, I need to be able to capture and export this data automatically for many devices.

I'm thinking the best way to get that data from so many iOS devices would be to build an app. The app would capture the iOS device's CPU, memory, and battery life, disk usage and running processes (basically, the same statistics as are generated in the Debug Instruments in Xcode), and then send the data to a database.

What frameworks or tools would be helpful for this?

Comment: Interesting question, This thread can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737621/trying-to-read-a-xcode-instruments-trace-file-what-is-the-file-format-of-a-tr

Comment: "Xcode", "Xcode", "Xcode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be best off using a solution such as New Relic's [mobile monitoring](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring) system. They allow you to monitor [performance across devices](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring#slide-feat-devices), [memory usage and time profiling](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring#slide-feat-diagnostics) and HTTP requests remotely just by dropping their SDK into your apps.