# How to automatically export Instruments data to CSV

Tags: ios, memory-management, automation, xcode-instruments

I'm looking at a way to automate the gathering of iOS memory usage.  So far, I've been using the Instruments cli to do this:

```
instruments -w <ID> -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Activity Monitor.tracetemplate" -l 30000
```

My problem now is exporting the data to be parsed.  I noticed in the Instruments GUI there is an option to export to CSV, however there doesn't appear to be anything like this for the CLI.

I unzipped the .trace package that the Instruments CLI outputs and found a lot of binary data, which isn't too useful.

Is it possible to export this data or convert it to a parsable format?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to specify a location in the command line argument for a .plist file to be exported to. You can parse a plist file with an xsl transformation.

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/2210287)