# How to parse .trace file from the instruments tool

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am trying to import the "Core Animation Frames per second" log into csv or excel file to be able to plot it and access it from my code for automation. Can someone let me know how to extract this data from the .trace file and export to a csv file?

Comment: Without going into a lot of details. It's possible to parse the data and save it as a CSV file but not an easy task. Please read this answer and hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/1883494

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. This is exactly what I was looking for