# How to read a Xcode 6.1 Instruments .trace file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, instruments

I have been trying to read a `.trace` file, which I had generated using a *custom* instruments template(instruments: *Automator*, *Allocations*, *Leaks*) using [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The best help I found in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/2210287). Basically the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350272/justsid) created a custom **Objective-C** program([Traced](https://github.com/JustSid/Traced)) to read a specific type of Apples `.trace` file(instrument: *OpenGL ES Driver*). His answer is geared towards **XCode 4.6**.

The code still works with **XCode 6.1**, but the trace-file seems to have changed slightly. You have to find the `*.run.zip` file within the `.trace` package and unzip it. In the extracted folder you now have to find the `*.run` file. There are several `*.run.zip` files in a `.trace` package; one per used instrument.

Simply running the [Traced](https://github.com/JustSid/Traced) program got me a `uncaught exception 'NSArchiverArchiveInconsistency', reason: '*** class error for 'XRObjectAllocRun'`-error.

This error was initially easy to figure out. All I had to do was implement the missing class `XRObjectAllocRun`; parallel to the example `XRRun` or `XRVideoCardRun` classes in [XRRun.m](https://github.com/JustSid/Traced/blob/master/Source/XRRun.m).

This is how far I got and where I got stuck:

```
#import "XRObjectAllocRun.h"

@implementation XRObjectAllocRun
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {   
        NSObject *a = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *b = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *c = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *d = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *e = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *f = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *g = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *h = [decoder decodeObject];
        NSObject *i = [decoder decodeObject];
//        NSObject *j = [decoder decodeObject];
//        NSObject *k = [decoder decodeObject];   
        NSLog(@"test");
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Basically I am stuck *reverse-engineering* the `XRObjectAllocRun` class. But no matter how many or little objects I decode I always receive the following exception: `uncaught exception 'NSArchiverArchiveInconsistency', reason: '*** NSUnarchiver: inconsistency between written and read data for object 0x100112750'`

If you uncomment the last two `decode` statements the program will crash with this exception: `uncaught exception 'NSArchiverArchiveInconsistency', reason: '*** file inconsistency: read 'i', expecting '@''`.

Does anyone know the signature of Apples XRObjectAllocRun class? This class is used for the *Allocations* instrument.

Any help would be great!

**Update**

I played around with **Swift** and translated the entire `*.trace`-reader - it fails with exactly the same error(s):

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

@objc(XRObjectAllocRun)
class XRObjectAllocRun: NSObject {
    func initWithCoder(decoder:NSCoder){
        var x = decoder.decodeObject()
        // this is where things start breaking...
    }
}

@objc(XRRun)
class XRRun: NSObject {
    // to be implemented    
}

@objc(XRTrackSegment)
class XRTrackSegment: NSObject {
    func initWithCoder(decoder:NSCoder)->NSString{
        var a = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var b = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var c = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var d = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var e = decoder.decodeObject()

        return "test"
    }
}

@objc(PFTTrackSegment)
class PFTTrackSegment: NSObject {
    func initWithCoder(decoder:NSCoder){
        var a = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var b = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var c = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var d = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var e = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
        var f = decoder.decodeObject()?.integerValue
    }
}

// parse command line
var traceFilePath = Process.arguments[1]
println("input: \(traceFilePath)")

var traceFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: traceFilePath)
var error:NSError?

// check if the file exists
if (traceFile?.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) == false){
    // file does not exist or cannot be accessed
    println("\(error)")
    exit(1)
}

var rawData = NSData(contentsOfURL: traceFile!)
var data = NSUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: rawData!)
var decodedObject: AnyObject? = data?.decodeObject()
println("\(decodedObject)")
```

Comment: Try to look here: https://github.com/JustSid/Traced
and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737621/trying-to-read-a-xcode-instruments-trace-file-what-is-the-file-format-of-a-tr
Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, but this is where I started from. I am using the code-example and describe how one can adapt it. Unfortunately I cannot figure out the signature as [JustSid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/350272/justsid) did.

Comment: @MarcoPashkov did you ever figured out how to parse the Allocations trace? I'm also stuck with same exceptions.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I made a bit more progress in **swift** - but it's not there yet. Once I figured it out I will post the answer. Also, since I am not working full-time on this issue I can't promise of reaching it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the signature of the `XRObjectAllocRun` class

```
#import "XRRun.h"

#import "SymbolAwareRun.h"
#import "XRCallTreeDataSource.h"
#import "XRSourceQuery.h"

@class NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary, NSString, XRHeapGeneration, XROAEventSummary, XRObjectAllocRunSharedData;

@interface XRObjectAllocRun : XRRun <SymbolAwareRun, XRSourceQuery, XRCallTreeDataSource>
{
    XRObjectAllocRunSharedData *_sharedData;
    NSMutableArray *_allStats;
    NSMutableDictionary *_statsForCategory;
    NSMutableDictionary *_categoryIDForName;
    XROAEventSummary *_scaleStats;
    NSMutableArray *_generations;
    struct XRTimeRange _filterTimeRange;
    unsigned int _filterMinEventID;
    unsigned int _filterMaxEventID;
    unsigned long long _nextGenNumber;
    NSMutableDictionary *_samplesByCategoryNumber;
    unsigned long long _catNumIndex;
    struct XRTimeRange _currentStatsFilterRange;
    int _lifecycleFilter;
    int _allocationTypeFilter;
    unsigned int *_quickEventCacheIds;
    id *_quickEventCache;
    XRHeapGeneration *_activeGeneration;
}

+ (void)initialize;
- (id)operation:(id)arg1 commentsForSymbol:(id)arg2 inSourceManager:(id)arg3 callTreeInformation:(id)arg4;
- (id)provideCategories;
- (id)backtracesForCategory:(id)arg1 timeRange:(struct XRTimeRange)arg2 savedIndex:(unsigned long long *)arg3;
- (void)_configureCallTreeForAllocationType:(int)arg1;
- (id)symbolsForEvent:(id)arg1 reverseOrder:(BOOL)arg2;
- (id)backtraceRepository;
- (BOOL)eventIsLiveInCurrentTimeRange:(id)arg1;
- (unsigned int)uncategorizedCount;
- (unsigned int)countOfObjectEventsForCategory:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)enumerateObjectEventsForCategory:(unsigned int)arg1 skipToIndex:(unsigned int)arg2 withBlock:(CDUnknownBlockType)arg3;
- (BOOL)_applyLifecycleFilterToEvent:(id)arg1;
- (id)zombieEvent;
- (id)eventForIdentifier:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (BOOL)loadDTPerformanceSessionDataFromPaths:(id)arg1 error:(id *)arg2;
- (void)updateGenerations;
- (void)deleteGeneration:(id)arg1;
- (void)moveGeneration:(id)arg1 toTime:(unsigned long long)arg2;
- (void)setActiveGeneration:(id)arg1;
- (id)generationAtTime:(unsigned long long)arg1;
- (id)generations;
- (id)nextGenerationIdentifier;
- (void)createGenerationAtTime:(unsigned long long)arg1;
- (void)removeFlag:(id)arg1;
- (struct XRTimeRange)_displayTimeFilter;
- (BOOL)_isTimeScoped;
- (BOOL)useTypeFilteringRules:(id)arg1;
- (void)setAllocationTypeFilter:(int)arg1;
- (void)setLifecycleFilter:(int)arg1;
- (struct XRTimeRange)selectedTimeRange;
- (void)setSelectedTimeRange:(struct XRTimeRange)arg1;
- (id)categoryNameForIdentifier:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (id)globalStats;
- (id)scalingStats;
- (void)_clearStats;
- (void)allowEventReuse;
- (void)refreshStatsForActiveTimeFilter;
- (void)_updateStatsWithEventIdentifier:(unsigned int)arg1 category:(unsigned int)arg2 type:(unsigned int)arg3 size:(int)arg4 pastEvent:(unsigned int)arg5 summaryMap:(id *)arg6 maxCat:(unsigned int)arg7;
- (id)_statsObjectForCategoryID:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)_changeStatsByTimestampRange:(struct XRTimeRange)arg1 overallRange:(struct XRTimeRange)arg2 startID:(unsigned int)arg3 endID:(unsigned int)arg4;
- (id *)_createCategorySummaryMapWithMaximum:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)_validateGlobalStatsForTimeRange:(struct XRTimeRange)arg1;
- (void)_recomputeGlobalStats;
- (BOOL)discardsLifeCycleComplete;
- (unsigned long long)lastTimestamp;
- (id)sharedData;
- (void)setRecordMode:(int)arg1;
- (void)setDiscardsLifeCycleComplete:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setTargetDevice:(id)arg1 pid:(int)arg2 repository:(id)arg3;
- (id)initWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (void)dealloc;
- (id)init;

// Remaining properties
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *debugDescription;
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *description;
@property(readonly) unsigned long long hash;
@property(readonly) Class superclass;

@end
```

I've uploaded signatures of other classes [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fh363xx1pytw6e0/instrdump.zip?dl=0) if you need them.

Instead of declaring required classes in Swift, you can simply import headers from the archive to the bridging header.

Comment: looks pretty good on an initial glance - I will take a deeper look over the weekend!

Comment: where did you find the headers?

Comment: @MarcoPashkov I used [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) to extract them from the binaries.

Comment: @MarcoPashkov were you able to parse the allocation data from the trace files? If so, can you give us an update? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, but I had to switch gears and abandon this project. But this seemed like it should work, since the API can be reverse reverse engineered by the tool that @bzz suggested. If you include the generated files you should be able to uncompress the data and read the traces.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. [Here](https://github.com/salabogdan/TraceParser) is the git project.