# How to change the namespace of a Swift class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6, nsarchiving

When you implement a class `MyGreatClass` in **Swift** its fully qualified name will by `<MyPackageName>.MyGreatClass`. This is different to **Objective-C**, where the fully qualified name of that same class is `MyGreatClass`.

Unfortunately this introduces a problem for me. When I am using `NSUnarchiver` and the archive was written with **Objective-C** objects I cannot unpack it with **Swift**-classes(see below for a detailed description).

This means I need to find a way to rename the namespace for my **Swift** classes. How do I do that?

Any help would be great!

### Background: Why can't NSUnarchiver see/load my swift class?

I have implemented a small program to read a file, which was archived with `NSArchive`.
These are my files:

`main.swift`:

```
import Foundation

// parse command line - total path to *.trace file (from Apple's Instruments app)
var traceFilePath = Process.arguments[1]

var traceFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: traceFilePath)
var error:NSError?

// check if the file exists
if (traceFile?.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error) == false){
    // file does not exist or cannot be accessed
    println("\(error)")
    exit(1)
}

var rawData = NSData(contentsOfURL: traceFile!)
var data = NSUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: rawData!)
var decodedObject: AnyObject? = data?.decodeObject()
```

`XRObjectAllocRun.swift`:

```
import Foundation

class XRObjectAllocRun: NSObject {
    // class to be implemented   
}
```

When I now run my application on an [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)-file I am getting the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSArchiverArchiveInconsistency', reason: '*** class error for 'XRObjectAllocRun': class not loaded'`.

This is really strange because when I add the exact same class in an **Objective-C** file with a  *bridging header* file I have no issues.

`trace file reader-Bridging-Header.h`: is empty.

`XRObjectAllocRun.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface XRObjectAllocRun : NSObject
@end
```

`XRObjectAllocRun.m`:

```
#import "XRObjectAllocRun.h"
@implementation XRObjectAllocRun
@end
```

What am I missing? Why is my `Objective-C` class found, whereas my `Swift` class is not?
Swift has no issues for example with `var x = XRObjectAllocRun()` in `main.swift`, but yet the `NSUnarchiver` still complaints about a missing `XRObjectAllocRun` class when I stay purely within `Swift`. Is the `NSUnarchiver` looking in the wrong places - does it for some reason only accept Objective-C classes?

If you want to know what I am trying to do check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951454/how-to-read-a-xcode-6-1-instruments-trace-file) out.

**Update**

This is what apple writes:

> Swift classes are namespaced based on the module they are compiled in, even when used from Objective-C code. Unlike Objective-C, where all classes are part of a global namespace

Further more:

> For example, when you create a document–based Mac app, you provide the name of your NSDocument subclass in your app’s Info.plist file. In Swift, you must use the full name of your document subclass, including the module name derived from the name of your app or framework.

Yikes, trying to figure out the mess now...

Comment: Could the problem be that there is no actual reference to XRObjectAllocRun in your code? I'm thinking it doesn't load unless some other code talks about it.

Comment: This is what I initially thought. But I added `var x = XRObjectAllocRun()` right before `var rawData = NSData(contentsOfURL: traceFile!)` and I still got the same error. When I inspect `x` before the crash I see `(trace_file_reader.XRObjectAllocRun) $R0 = 0x0000000102000040 (ObjectiveC.NSObject = {})`

Comment: this is the what the `Objective-C` object prints out on the debug console: `(XRObjectAllocRun) $R0 = 0x00000001020004b0 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}`.  Notice the *difference*: (**swift**) `trace_file_reader.XRObjectAllocRun` vs (**ObjC**) `XRObjectAllocRun`. Can I remove the namespace somehow in swift?

Comment: Yes, you can declare it with `@objc(XRObjectAllocRun)`. I think that's probably the answer here. I'll give it as an answer!

Comment: Well done, you really got this question revised and focussed nicely after all your detective work. I couldn't have thought of the answer otherwise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this when you declare your class:

```
@objc(XRObjectAllocRun) class XRObjectAllocRun: NSObject {
    // class to be implemented   
}
```

That will give this class the same name as the archived class, namely `XRObjectAllocRun`, instead of the namespaced Swift name `trace_file_reader.XRObjectAllocRun`.

This is always a concern when you're translating from Objective-C to Swift and you've got an existing archive to deal with. See Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Note the discussion under "Exposing Swift Interfaces in Objective-C".

Comment: And I talk about some other places where `@objc(...)` is useful, in my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects