# I want to create a dashboard using .traces file after profiling(Xcode Instrument). Is it possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, instruments, heap-memory

What is alternative for MAT in iOS ?

I want to create a dashboard using ".traces" file after profiling. Is it possible ? If yes how ?Kindly share relevant link .

Comment: By dashboard, do you mean a summary of multiple trace files - all parsed from specific data within the .traces files?

Comment: Yes , exactly . I want to collect trace data and parse them

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several open source projects attempting to parse and extract data from Instruments .traces files. In no particular order:

1. [Traced](https://github.com/JustSid/Traced)
2. [TraceUtility](https://github.com/Qusic/TraceUtility)
3. [InstrumentsParser](https://github.com/powerli/InstrumentsParser)

None of the projects I've looked at are ideal because Apple doesn't maintain the .traces format with the intent of anything other than Instruments reading it.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743749/5499522) walks through some of the file format structure details.

***Ideally*** in the future Apple will offer an option to export to some standard formats. Until then you'll have to use or extend these parsing libraries to dig through the data blob.

Comment: @bablu-joshi add a comment if you find something better! I've worked on this same problem just a bit, but had to move on to other projects.